# How to show immediately ProgressBar dialog in Java?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I created a progressbar dialog in a separate java file:

```
public class AppUtil {
    // progress bar handling
    public static Dialog showProgress(Activity activity) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(0));
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress);
        ProgressBar progressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.fore_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

and it has its own `RelativeLayout` xml resource layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_progress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but if I call it in a play button progressbar doesn't show immediately but only when `onClick` button is finished:

```
ImageButton buttonPlay = (ImageButton) currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.play);
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // play streaming
        SingleAudio sd = getItem(position);
        if (sd == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        dialog = AppUtil.showProgress(adapterActivity);
        sd.playerInstance.setDialog(dialog);

        if (sd.playerInstance.inPlay()) {
            sd.playerInstance.stop();
        } else {
            sd.playerInstance.play();
        }
    }
});
```

where right after I call `showProgress()` , I pass the dialog to the player instance to dismiss the dialog once the song playing is started and the button play is changed to stop play.... I tried also to put `showProgress()` inside an `adapterActivity.runOnUiThread` too but it doesn't show immediately... I wanted to show immediately to prevent user to click again buttons and wait if the play process is completely started....shall I have missed something to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 ImageButton buttonPlay = (ImageButton) currentItemView.findViewById(R.id.play);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Disable the button to prevent multiple clicks
            buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
    
            // Show the progress dialog immediately
            dialog = AppUtil.showProgress(adapterActivity);
    
            // Start a background thread for audio playback
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Play streaming on the background thread
                    SingleAudio sd = getItem(position);
                    if (sd != null) {
                        sd.playerInstance.setDialog(dialog);
    
                        if (sd.playerInstance.inPlay()) {
                            sd.playerInstance.stop();
                        } else {
                            sd.playerInstance.play();
                        }
                    }
    
                    // Dismiss the progress dialog on the main UI thread
                    adapterActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            // Re-enable the button when the operation is finished
                            buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Sarmad Ali , your suggest was helpful , with the little exception to dismiss dialog and re-enable button only when I know if the state is really played because I change the button image to stop and viceversa.. Even I tried to use Thread but just I had to encapsulate the play code , not the `showProgress()` itself... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

You just register the dialog into the WindowManager when you invoke the `dialog.show()` method. It's up to Android System to show the  dialog content (later).

I recommend to use a LiveData to observe the player state and toggle the dialog in the observer.

It's recommended to use DialogFragment rather than Dialog.